# Integral closure in an infinite algebraic extension

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory

If $A$ is a principal ideal domain and $L/Q(A)$ a finite field extension, then it follows from Krull-Akizuki theorem that the integral closure of $A$ in $L$ is a Dedekind domain. Now if $L/Q(A)$ is an infinite algebraic extension, can we say that the integral closure of $A$ in $L$ is not Noetherian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral closure of $\Bbb{Z}_p$ ($p$-adic integers) in $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^n-1})$ is the DVR
$\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\Bbb{Z}_p[\zeta_{p^n-1}]$ (in particular Noetherian).

So there is no easy rule.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for. I didn't expect such rings to be Noetherian, but here's an example! Actually, what i want to prove, is apparently a result due to Gilmer. It says that if $F$ is an infinite algebraic extension over either $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb F_p(t)$, then $F$ contains a non-Noetherian ring. Do you have any idea about how to prove it?